# Chart in Android (2D or 3D)

Tags: android, charts

I would like to know what are the available api (free and paid) to make chart in 2D or 3D for android.

If anyone knows I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [**MPAndroidChart**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

**Core features:**

- 5 chart types (line, bar, pie, scatter, candlestick)
- Scaling on both axes (with touch-gesture, axes separately or pinch-zoom)
- Dragging (with touch-gesture)
- Highlighting values (with customizeable popup-views)
- Save chart to SD-Card (as image, or as .txt file)
- Read .txt file chart-data
- Predefined color templates
- Legends (generated automatically, customizeable)
- Labels (both x- and y-axis, customizeable)
- Animations (build up animations, on both x- and y-axis)
- Limit lines (providing additional information, maximums, ...)
- Fully customizeable (paints, typefaces, legends, colors, background, gestures, dashed lines, ...)

Comment: I'm trying to use it but it is giving me an error, "Could not find class 'com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart', referenced from method com.example.charts.MPAndroidchart_show.create_chart" when I declare the LineChart chart = new LineChart(context);

Comment: It looks like you havent properly imported the library. Are you using eclipse? What did you do to import and add the library?

Comment: Yes i am using eclipse, i follow these steps https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/26

Comment: Can MPAndroidChart be used to plot mathematical relations like Circle (X^2+Y^2=10)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of libraries for graph.

http://android-graphview.org/

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView

http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Answer (score 1):

For 3D charts, my company has this product:

http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html

There is a demo on the app store:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orsoncharts.android.demo

[image]